# Why does GetCommandLineArgs return a DLL when running pwsh.exe?

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-core

I am running the following command as part of a test code trying to determine if a script is running in an interactive session (i.e. with a CLI) or if from a console-less remote session (SSH,SCP,FTP).

So when using `[Environment]::GetCommandLineArgs()`, in a *Powershell Core* (`pwsh.exe`) CLI session, I get: **`C:\Program Files\PowerShell\6\pwsh.dll`**. This is surprising as I would have expected to get **pwsh.exe** and not a DLL.

**Why do I get the DLL and not the EXE?**
What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a **known problem** that is still not fixed as of .NET 5.0, which PowerShell Core 7.1 is built on (both are in preview as of this writing, but I don't expect a fix to come in time for these releases).

See [GitHub issue #11305](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/11305).

However, there is a **workaround** that is actually ***generally* preferable**:

```
[System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName

# Shorter, but slower equivalent (works only from PowerShell):
#  (Get-Process -Id $PID).MainModule.FileName
```

The reason that `[System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName` is preferable to `[Environment]::GetCommandLineArgs()[0]` is twofold:

- The former *always* reports a *full* path.
- At least up to .NET Core 3.1, the latter can report a *temporary location*, namely for single-file .NET Core executables that extract themselves to such locations behind the scenes.

Note that **.NET 5.0+ will have a dedicated `[Environment]::ProcessPath` property** that will also perform better - see [GitHub PR #42768](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/42768).

---

If you want to get a *corrected* version of `[Environment]::GetCommandLineArgs()` - that is, with the real executable stored at index `0` and the true *arguments* in the remaining elements:

```
# Get the original array...
# Note: Modifying the array directly works, but you can enclose 
#       the call in @(...) in order to create a *copy* of it.
$cmdLineArgs = [Environment]::GetCommandLineArgs()
# ... and fix the entry for the executable (index 0)
$cmdLineArgs[0] = [Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName
```

To demonstrate with an invocation of the PowerShell CLI from `cmd.exe`:

```
C:>pwsh -noprofile -c "$a=[Environment]::GetCommandLineArgs(); $a[0]=[Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName; $a"
C:\Program Files\PowerShell\6\pwsh.exe
-noprofile
-c
$a=[Environment]::GetCommandLineArgs(); $a[0]=[Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName; $a
```